# A Monster of A Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, english

On my own I am large,

But give me fruit,

Or an insect,

Or even a flower,

I'll grow small.

Take any letter away and rearranged,

You could have hundreds,

Maybe an instrument,

Perhaps one element,

Or even two.

**What word am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are a ...

> dragon.

On my own I am large,

> Dragons are large mythical beasts.

But give me fruit, or an insect, or even a flower, I'll grow small.

> Dragon fruit, dragonflies and dragon orchids are all quite small compared to a dragon.

Take any letter away and rearranged, You could have hundreds,

> Take away the **o** to get an anagram of **grand**, a thousand or "hundreds".

Maybe an instrument,

> Take away the **d** to get an anagram of **organ**, a musical instrument.

Perhaps one element,

> Take away the **g** to get an anagram of the chemical element **radon**.

Or even two.

> Alternatively, remove the **d** to get argon.

The title ...

> has the hint "A Monster of a Riddle". Dragons are common monsters in role-playing games, especially in *Dungeons and Dragons*.

Comment: Perfect answer!